# Smart grid communications

Tags: power-engineering, power-line-communication, smart

For my final project, I am looking about smart grid. What I want to know is that what kind of communication is done in smart grid and the appliances, protocols used etc.

Can I extract a data whether the grid is peak or off-peak?
I have read many papers, but couldn't find an answer for this.

Sorry if this is a wrong forum to post this question

Comment: The smart grid hasn't widely been adopted

Comment: "peak or off-peak" - times? If you're interested in the *generation* side, there's quite a lot of stats available eg http://gridwatch.templar.co.uk/

Comment: @laptop2d yes, that is true. this is for a final project.

Comment: @pjc50 thanks, but I want to know whether I can extract it as a data from client side using smart grid communication line.

Comment: How do we know? it depends on how the system is implemented. This is not a problem of communication.